# iOS UIApplication windows setEnabled error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8, uiapplication

With the latest `XCode (8.0 (8a218a)` release, my app now fails to build with the error message

> "No known instance method for selector 'setEnabled'"

Here is the code, error flagged at the second last line. -

```
if (alertView.tag == PURCHASE_TAG) {
    //NSLog(@"***Purchasing****");
    /*
     [BaseFunctions deleteKeychainValue:@"InstallDate"];
     [BaseFunctions createKeychainValue:[BaseFunctions getCurrentYearMonthDate] forIdentifier:@"InstallDate"];
     NSData *passwordData = [BaseFunctions searchKeychainCopyMatching:@"InstallDate"];
     if (passwordData) {
     installDate = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:passwordData
     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     }
     NSLog(@"***InstallDate = %@", installDate);
     */
    [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Purchasing"];
    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:0] setEnabled:NO];
    [[InAppPurchaseHandler sharedInAppPurchaseHandler] getProductInfoList];
}
```

I can't find any reference to the `setEnabled` parameter and I am not sure how the line should be modified.

Comment: please check which type return controller after set enabled?

Answer (score 0):

`UIView` does not have a `setEnabled:` selector, but it has a `setUserInteractionEnabled:` selector which disables user interaction with the `UIView`.

```
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:0] setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

It does however not change the visual state of the `UIView` but that might also not be the intention.

Answer (score -1):

```
UIView *window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:0];
[window setEnabled:NO];
```

Comment: Who is that down vote this one without any explanation